# How to determine if a number is any type of int (core or numpy, signed or not)?

Tags: python, numpy, types

I need to test whether a variable is of type `int`, or any of `np.int*`, `np.uint*`, preferably using a single condition (*i.e.* no `or`).

After some tests, I guess that:

- `isinstance(n, int)` will only match `int` and `np.int32` (or `np.int64` depending on plateform),
- `np.issubdtype(type(n), int)` seems to match all `int` and `np.int*`, but doesn’t match `np.uint*`.

This leads to two questions: will `np.issubdtype` match **any** kind of signed ints? Can determine in a single check whether a number is any kind of signed or unsigned int?

This is about testing for **integers**, the test should return `False` for float-likes.

Comment: Consider using `isinstance(n, numbers.Integral)` if you want to avoid importing NumPy.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

NumPy provides base classes that you can/should use for subtype-checking, rather than the Python types.

Use `np.integer` to check for any instance of either signed or unsigned integers.

Use `np.signedinteger` and `np.unsignedinteger` to check for signed types or unsigned types.

```
>>> np.issubdtype(np.uint32, np.integer)
True
>>> np.issubdtype(np.uint32, np.signedinteger)
False
>>> np.issubdtype(int, np.integer)
True
>>> np.issubdtype(np.array([1, 2, 3]).dtype, np.integer)
True
```

All floating or complex number types will return `False` when tested.

`np.issubdtype(np.uint*, int)` will always be `False` because the Python `int` is a signed type.

A useful reference showing the relationship between all of these base classes is found in the documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html).

[image]

Comment: I’m definitely voting up, this allows for testing with: `isinstance(n, (int, np.integer))`.

Comment: @ArcturusB: I'm confused by your comment because I get False for both of these statements: `isinstance(np.array(1, dtype=np.int32), np.int32)` and `isinstance(np.array(1, dtype=np.int32), np.integer)`

Comment: @ArcturusB, you are testing an array against an integer type, so you get the False result. try `isinstance(np.int32(1), np.int32) `

Comment: I find it odd that `np.issubdtype( int, np.integer )` is True:
`int` can be as long as fits in memory, 
`np.integer( sys.maxsize ** 2 )` raises
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long.

Comment: @khaverim isinstance(np.array(1, dtype=np.int32).dtype, np.integer) returns False ...

Comment: @agemO Oops. here. `np.issubdtype(np.array(1, dtype=np.int32).dtype, np.integer)` returns `True`

Answer (score 10):

I suggest passing a tuple of types to python `isinstance()` built-in function. And regarding to your question about `np.issubtype()` it doesn't match any kind of signed ints, it determine if a class is a subclass of a second class. And since all of integer types (int8, int32, etc.) are subclasses of `int` it will return True if you pass any of these type along with `int`.

Here is an example:

```
>>> a = np.array([100])
>>> 
>>> np.issubdtype(type(a[0]), int)
True
>>> isinstance(a[0], (int, np.uint))
True
>>> b = np.array([100], dtype=uint64)
>>> 
>>> isinstance(b[0], (int, np.uint))
True
```

Also, as a more generic approach (is not appropriate when you only want to match some specific types) you can use `np.isreal()`:

```
>>> np.isreal(a[0])
True
>>> np.isreal(b[0])
True
>>> np.isreal(2.4) # This might not be the result you want
True
>>> np.isreal(2.4j)
False
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications about `np.issutype()`. I guess listing types in `isinstance()` would work, but I want to avoid this as it would imply doing `isinstance(n, (int, np.int, np.int0, np.int8, np.int16, <etc.>, np.uint, <etc.>)`. I can’t think less pythonic.

Comment: @ArcturusB In that case you might  want to use a more generic type, and parent types of integers. Take a look at numpy data typing http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.types.html

Comment: Indeed, using `np.integer` as suggested by ajcr works fine; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on fabulous @Alex Riley answer with the tree-types I managed to solve the same problem by mapping my values to this fn. Hope it is useful for someone.

```python
def convert_to_native_type(value):
    if isinstance(value, np.integer):
        return int(value)
    elif isinstance(value, np.float):
        return float(value)
    else:
        return value
```