# How can I identify numpy's integer type?

Tags: python, numpy

What is the simplest way to identify whether a data point in numpy's `array` is an integer? Currently I use `numpy.dtype(x[i]).type` to return the type of the element `i` of array `x` and then

```
`if numpy.dtype(x[i]).type is numpy.int*`
```

to achieve this, where `*` can be `8`, `32` or `64`. But it may also return `uint`, thus this `if` way can return `False`. I wonder whether there exists a simple way to identify whether it is an integer, regardless of the exact `int` type is. And how about float?

Comment: Does `numpy.dtype(x[i])` even work? What is `x`? If it's numeric, I get `TypeError: data type not understood`

Comment: Sorry, try `x = np.array([1,2,3,4,6,7])` and `np.dtype(x[0])`

Comment: TIL that `np.dtype` works on array scalars to retrieve the type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this might help (this effectively tests for a signed integer, in a similar [fashion](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html#numpy.dtype.kind) 'u' would be unsigned integer, etc.):

```
x[i].dtype.kind == 'i'
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like to accept this answer as it is consistent with the [definition of numpy's data types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) and makes sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
issubdtype(var, type)
```

Usage:

```
numpy.issubdtype(var_to_check, np.integer)
```

More information here [How to determine if a number is any type of int (core or numpy, signed or not)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726830/how-to-determine-if-a-number-is-any-type-of-int-core-or-numpy-signed-or-not)

Answer (score 1):

Use either:

```
 issubclass(x[i].dtype.type, np.integer)
```

or

```
 np.issubdtype(x[i].dtype, np.integer)
```

Your code of `np.dtype(x)` is unlikely to do what you want - that doesn't get the dtype of `x`, but tries to interpret x as a description of a new dtype. If you have a possibly non-numpy object you want a dtype of, you can use `np.asanyarray(x).dtype`