# How to merge rows in dataframe with different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to merge rows of dataframe with one common column value and then merge rest of the column values separated by comma for string values and convert to array/list for int values.

```py
A   B     C    D
1  one   100  value
4  four  400  value
5  five  500  value
2  two   200  value
```

Expecting result like:

```py
   A                B                 C            D
[1,4,5,2]  one,four,five,two  [100,400,500,200]  value
```

I can use groupby for column D but how can I use apply for columns A,C as apply(np.array) and apply(','.join) for column B in df all at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = df.groupby('D').apply(lambda x: pd.Series([list(x.A),','.join(x.B),list(x.C)])).reset_index().rename({0:'A',1:'B',2:'C'}, axis=1)

df = df[['A','B','C','D']]
```

**Output**

```
              A                  B                     C      D
0  [1, 4, 5, 2]  one,four,five,two  [100, 400, 500, 200]  value
```

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic solution - strings columns are joined and numeric are converted to lists with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
f = lambda x: x.tolist() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else ','.join(x)
#similar for test strings - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37727662
#f = lambda x: ','.join(x) if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.flexible) else x.tolist()
df1 = df.groupby('D').agg(f).reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
              A                  B                     C      D
0  [1, 4, 5, 2]  one,four,five,two  [100, 400, 500, 200]  value
```

Another solution is specify each functions separately for each column:

```
df2 = (df.groupby('D')
        .agg({'A': lambda x: x.tolist(), 'B': ','.join, 'C':lambda x: x.tolist()})
        .reset_index()
        .reindex(columns=df.columns))

print (df2)

              A                  B                     C      D
0  [1, 4, 5, 2]  one,four,five,two  [100, 400, 500, 200]  value
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not a one-liner `agg`:

```
>>> df.groupby('D', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: x.tolist() if x.dtype != object else ','.join(x))[df.columns]
              A                  B                     C      D
0  [1, 4, 5, 2]  one,four,five,two  [100, 400, 500, 200]  value
>>>
```