# How to see if a given dtype is a subdtype of multiple numpy dtypes?

Tags: python, numpy

As an example, I want to check if a given datatype is one of the below. If I was dealing with Python dtypes then I would simply check as in the below example.

```
>>> my_var = 5
>>> type(my_var) in (bool, int, float)
True

>>> my_var = 5.0
>>> type(my_var) in (bool, int, float)
True
```

Now, what I want is to use something like [`numpy.issubdtype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.issubdtype.html) in order to do the same check as above for the corresponding numpy datatypes. So that I'm checking if `my_var` is a sub data type of `np.integer`, `np.float`, `np.bool`. I was hoping I could do this in a nice / pythonic way without having to use multiple `or` operators as below.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> my_var = 5
>>> np.issubdtype(type(my_var), np.bool) or np.issubdtype(type(my_var), np.integer) or np.issubdtype(type(my_var), np.float)
True
```

p.s. I know there will be a warning about `np.bool` being deprecated, but I'm trying to simplify my example here.

Comment: why not do the same thing in ur code? `type(my_var) in (np.bool, np.int, np.float)` which returns `True`

Comment: @sharathnatraj The requirement is to check if it is a subtype. Not if it's exactly, `np.int`. For example, If it is `np.int64`, `np.int32`, or even just `int`. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37727662/11542679) to see what I mean.

Comment: According to the hierarchy in https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html, `np.number` covers both integers and floats, but `np.bool_` is off on a branch of its own.